# https in myapp.appspot.com throws me an error in Firefox when not logged in

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firefox, ssl, https

I want to access myapp.appspot.com through https.

In `app.yaml` I have done this configuration:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  login: optional
  secure: always
```

When accessing it with Firefox, it throws me this error without being able to access the page.

```
Your connection is not secure

The owner of www.myapp.appspot.com has configured their website improperly. 
To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox may only connect to it securely.
As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.
```

- I have tested my web using Chrome, and it works.

I found this in App Engine docs:

```
It is possible to use to use Strict-Transport-Security in your App engine.
In order to add HTTP Strict-Transport-Security headers (HTST)
to your app, you must be implement the headers within your app's code,
not within your app's config file (app.yaml or appengine-web.xml).
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#hsts

But I don't know what it means.

What Am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried it without the www ?

Comment: Thanks. This worked......................................................

Comment: Really can't believe it. This is super hilarious.

Comment: Would you state an answer so I can accept it? An answer is an answer.

Comment: Great :) Yes - sometimes these little things catch you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
https://www.myapp.appspot.com
```

try

```
https://myapp.appspot.com
```

i.e. without the www. I believe GAE doesn't support sub-sub domains except for the case of version numbers.